# Android kotlin: putParcelableArrayList(ArrayList<int>) and getParcelableArrayList<Int>() wont work

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, parcelable

I am trying to pass `ArrayList<Integer>` from fragment to another fragment, here is my code:

**Kotlin code**

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(categoryId: Int, brandsList: ArrayList<Int>): Fragment {
        val fragment = CategoryAllAdsFragment()
        fragment.arguments = Bundle()
        fragment.arguments!!.putInt(Constant.CATEGORY_ID, categoryId)
        fragment.arguments!!.putParcelableArrayList(Constant.BRANDS_LIST, brandsList)
        return fragment
    }
}
```

but it says:

> Type mismatch.
>
> Required: java.util.ArrayList !
>
> Found: kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* = java.util.ArrayList */

The same thing when I was trying to read it.

**Kotlin code**

```
try {
    val brandsList = arguments!!.getParcelableArrayList<Int>(Constant.BRANDS_LIST)
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    throw Exception("brand list cannot be null")
}
```

It says:

> Type argument is not within its bounds
>
> Expected: Parcelable!
>
> Found: Int

I've tested it with `Java` and its work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

> - putIntegerArrayList(String key, ArrayList value)
> - Inserts an ArrayList value into the mapping of this Bundle, replacing any
>     existing value for the given key

```
putIntegerArrayList(Constant.BRANDS_LIST, array)
```

And get like

> - getIntegerArrayList(String key)
> - Returns the value associated with the given key, or null if no mapping
>     of the desired type exists for the given key or a null value is
>     explicitly associated with the key.

```
extras.getIntegerArrayList(Constant.BRANDS_LIST)
```

Comment: the `extras.getIntArray(Constant.BRANDS_LIST)` maybe will work, but there is no `putExtra(Constant.BRANDS_LIST, array)` in `Bundle`

Answer (score 8):

You can make a general Parcelable class that contains a variable of type (Any)

```
class BaseParcelable : Parcelable {

    var value: Any

    constructor(value: Any) {
        this.value = value
    }

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) {
        this.value = Any()
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {}

    override fun describeContents(): Int = 0

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<BaseParcelable> {

        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): BaseParcelable {
            return BaseParcelable(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<BaseParcelable?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this class to pass data between fragments or between (Activty to Fragment)

To pass list from fragment to fragment for example:

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(categoryId: Int, brandsList: ArrayList<Int>): Fragment {
       val fragment = CategoryAllAdsFragment()
       fragment.arguments = Bundle()
       fragment.arguments!!.putInt(Constant.CATEGORY_ID, categoryId)
       fragment.arguments!!.putParcelable(Constant.BRANDS_LIST, BaseParcelable(brandsList))
       return fragment
    }
}
```

To get the list:

```
val any = arguments?.getParcelable<BaseParcelable>(Constant.BRANDS_LIST).value
val list = any as ArrayList<Int>
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList